# How does Zend Framework still work when my database adapter is null?

Tags: zend-framework

So, I am looking at this documentation page here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/learning.multiuser.authentication.html

I tested it out, and it turns out this line: `$this->_getParam('db');` dumps as `null`. So I wanted to ask if someone could explain to me the behaviors of Zend Framework. If the db adapter is null, then how is the rest of the script even working? Does it automatically go to the application.ini to get the db adapter information? Also, where is `$this->_getParam('db')` supposedly getting the parameter 'db' from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon how you instantiate your db adapter and then use it.

If you use the [db application resource plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.db) using something like the following in `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
resources.db.adapter          = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host      = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username  = "myuser"
resources.db.params.password  = "mypass"
resources.db.params.dbname    = "mydatabase"
```

then this adapter gets set (by default) as the default adapter to use for `Zend_Db_Table` and its subclasses (which may include some of your models).